# Buffer listener to server output ERROR

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a problem with listening to my server output. I would like to be able to print something to the console as soon as one of the quoted command. The problem that I face is that it seems to be listening but then not go along with the rest of the program. So when I try to click on a button on my GUI, it get stuck.

```
public class MainFrame implements Runnable {
    //declare Jpanel
    private static JFrame frmHome;

    // The client socket
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    // The output stream
    static ObjectOutputStream os;
    // The input stream
    static ObjectInputStream is;
    private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
    private static boolean closed = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // The default port.
        int portNumber = 3333;
        // The default host.
        String host = "localhost";
        /*
         * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
         */
        try {
          clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
          is = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.flush();
          System.out
          .println("CONNECTED TO SERVER\n"
              + "Now using host=" + host + ", portNumber=" + portNumber);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
              + host);
        }

        /*
         * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data to the
         * socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber.
         */
        if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
          /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
          new Thread(new MainFrame()).start();
          os.writeObject("Home");
          os.flush();
        }
      }

      public void run() {
        /*
         * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the
         * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
         */
          MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
          MainFrame.frmHome.setVisible(true);
        String responseLine;
        try {
          while (!closed) {
```

Here is where I try to create my buffer reader. The 2 commands "Modify,OK" and "AdStudent ok", are coming after other parts of the GUI have successfully performed a task.

```
              BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String line;
              try {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    if (br.readLine().contains("Modify,OK") 
                            || br.readLine().contains("AddSudent ok")){
                        System.out.println("did it");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
          }
        } finally{
            try {
                is.close();
                os.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }

    public MainFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    //function to make window visible
    void setVisible() throws IOException {
        main(null);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        //Initialise Main window with 3 options.
        frmHome = new JFrame();
        frmHome.setTitle("Home");
        frmHome.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 372);
        frmHome.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHome.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frmHome.setResizable(false);

        JLabel lblWelcomeToSrs = new JLabel("Welcome to SRS");
        lblWelcomeToSrs.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblWelcomeToSrs.setBounds(86, 183, 112, 14);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToSrs);

        //initialise all buttons and labels of window.
        JButton btnAdStu = new JButton("Add a student");
        btnAdStu.setBounds(10, 207, 126, 23);
        btnAdStu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                AddStudentFrame adus;
                try {
                    try {
                        adus = new AddStudentFrame();
                        adus.setVisible();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    frmHome.setVisible(false);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(btnAdStu);

        JButton btnCheckStud = new JButton("Search / Modify");
        btnCheckStud.setBounds(146, 207, 127, 23);
        btnCheckStud.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                SearchFrame searchFrame;
                searchFrame = new SearchFrame();
                searchFrame.setVisible();
            }
        });
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(btnCheckStud);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblCreatedByRmi = new JLabel("Created by R\u00E9mi Tuyaerts");
        lblCreatedByRmi.setBounds(147, 318, 184, 14);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblCreatedByRmi);  

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Complete List of Students");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                CompleteListFrame studentList = new CompleteListFrame();
                studentList.setVisible();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(52, 241, 184, 23);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        // wonderful pictures of his excellence design by Yasser
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
        Image img = new ImageIcon(frmHome.getClass().getResource("/michaelchung.jpg")).getImage();
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(80, 11, 120, 148);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is not good here I guess 
     `if (br.readLine().contains("Modify,OK") 
                            || br.readLine().contains("AddSudent ok")){
                        System.out.println("did it");
                    }`
When you say `br.readLine()` it will go to the next line I think you should compare using `line.contains("Your Command")`

Comment: hmmm no it doesn't seem to work sorry :/

Comment: Whats the error in console ... ?]

Comment: no error, it just get stuck, like if it was in an infinite loop